# Linking to a library that links to a library

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, codeblocks, sfml

I'm trying to link [`cpgui`](http://www.sfml-dev.org/wiki/en/projects/cpgui) to my library, which links to `SFML`. I use `code::blocks` so I had to make my own project for that library, and as it requires `SFML` I statically linked to `SFML` in that library and compiled it fine.

Now, when I attempt to statically link that library to my library, I get a bunch of **undefined references to `SFML`** when I compile my project. Even if I linked to `SFML` in both projects, what's happening?

Comment: You should be able to just link to the library you want to use. That library should have been compiled and linked against any dependencies it had and if it's all static you don't even need to deploy anything but your app or whatever you're making.  However you should check that you don't have conflicting versions of SFML or other common dependencies across projects.

Comment: I compiled it myself and linked against my version of SFML, so it's probably either a bug with my linker or a bug with that project. Oh well. I got it to work anyway.

Comment: Out of curiosity what was the solution?

Comment: Instead of linking the library, I simply added the source files to the current project.

Comment: Ah well I guess that's one way to do it if it's open source and you were going to statically link anyway :P

Answer (score 0):

As you guessed, you can make it simpler by **adding the library files directly to the project**.

Another solution as suggested by AJG85 would have been to link the library  -- after taking care of conflicting dependencies.

Use relevant documentation as suggested by answer to [How do I link a library to my project in CodeBlocks & GCC without adding the library source to my project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21127038/how-do-i-link-a-library-to-my-project-in-codeblocks-gcc-without-adding-the-lib)